# Debug Python package inside of container using VSCode

Tags: python, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

I followed the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-python) and were able to set up the debugging inside a docker container.

Now, I would like to jump into a certain function of a package, let's say `numpy.random.randint` to check its behaviour. If I click on `Step Into` unfortunately the program continues with the next line instead of jumping into the package.
Assuming that the package is not installed locally, is it even possible to do following in VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the launch.json file:

```
"justMyCode": false,
```

[image]

Comment: I did but it didn’t change anything

Comment: @oezguensi You still can not jump into the package? just continues with the next line as before?

Comment: @oezguensi I test locally, and I can get into fromnumeric.py.

Comment: @oezguensi Does it like the picture in the answer?

Comment: yes it is at the exact same place. Do you have numpy installed locally?

Comment: @oezguensi Yes, I can jump into fromnumeric.py as like as the Pycharm does.

Comment: But are you running it inside a Docker container?